# Raspberry run video in lite version

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspbian, vlc

i have a raspberry 5 with Raspbian bookworm lite connected to a screen via hdmi cable.
I'm trying to play a video using VLC from command line via ssh from another machine, but what happens is that the video starts inside the terminal in a strange textual mode!

How can i run the video on the connected screen?
Thanks

I think that the X server is missing but i'm not an expert in that

Comment: I'm sure it's not the answer you're looking for but since I've been watching this Q since yesterday and nobody has spoken up, I will. I'm pretty sure there's no way around requiring having the GUI (X for example) present if you want to feed video out to HDMI (or any other physical video out). And since you mention you're using Raspbian LITE, which by definition does not include any GUI (Command line only) it would make sense that you aren't getting anything. That said, you're on the right track, VLC is the best option, IMO. I suggest installing x and proceeding
`apt install xserver-xorg`